# How I can search what is call my function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For example I have some function like the following:

```
function Example() {
    console.log('do something');
}
```

When I run javascript console in Google Chrome, I can see something like:

```
2 do something                        script_file.js
```

Oops, I see that my function is called twice. I want to find events or functions that call my function Example(). How I can do it? May be browser plugin is exists, or I don't know something about Chrome developer tools.

I need in solution for Chrome only.

Comment: If you use `console.error` instead of `console.log`, you should get a stacktrace in your console (click on the black triangle to see it).

Comment: It isn't my wish. I want to get something like: do something - script_file.js (event.[HTMLObject].click), do something - script_file.js (function PrintDoSomething())

Comment: You can't see what event led to the execution of the function, only what function called it. If you want to format your own stack trace (as you seem to), you will need to parse the stack trace yourself. `new Error().stack` will give you the string representation that you can cut as you wish.

Comment: You wrote: "You can't see what event led to the execution of the function". May be somebody will disagree with you..

Comment: Let me amend. If you're using jQuery events (or events provided by some other library), you could inject a spy around `on` that would let you see event triggers. If you are using native events, you can't do that. You could have an additional `addEventListener` which would remember the event type as it happens, but it would not be connected to your stacktrace. I'm sticking with "can't", given how your question is worded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller).

```
function a() {
    console.log(a.caller);
}
function b() {
    a();
}
b();    // function b() { a(); }
```

Or you can use the profiler tool in chrome. Start recording, perform the action, stop the recording, it will list all the actions, the function calls from which file etc. I recommend this approach.

Comment: It's interesting solution, but it is ugly to add caller function into all my functions that I want debug. May be exists some extension for chrome devtools to get caller.

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.trace()`. You can use it with or without an argument and it will supply you with a complete stack trace in your browser console.

You can use it with arguments too.

```
console.trace( this );
```

You can also add a [breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints) in your code and see the call stack when it is called, and even see the arguments and variable values.

I hope this answers your question.